# Formula of joint pdf

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, marginal-distribution, marginal-probability

Let $\Omega$ be a sample space and $\mathbb{Q}=(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ standard probability space. Suppose that there exeist three different functions, say

$$\mu:\Omega\to\Delta(X)$$

$$\tau:X\to\Delta(T)$$
and
$$\phi:X\times Y\to \Delta(\Xi)$$

they induce a probability distribution on $X\times Y\times \Xi$ and $\mu_{\Xi}(\omega)$ is the marginal distribution on $\Xi$.

What is the formula of the marginal distributuion $\mu_{\Xi}(\omega)$ and the other marginals with respect to $X$ and $Y$ and what is the formula of the joint pdf?

Comment: What do you mean with notations like $\Delta(X)$?

Comment: @drhab this $\Delta$ denotes the simplex of the set $X$ and the same hols for the rest of the sets